# can you rotate two edges symetrically without mirror modifier?

Tags: workflow, transforms, mirror

For example, if I have two edges like these:[image]

and when I rotate them, I want them to rotate in opposite directions, like when you use the mirror modifier so that it looks ike this:
[image]

I was wondering if there's a way to do this *without* the mirror modifier because sometimes I just want to select two edges or faces in a mesh and either translate or rotate them symmetrically.

Answer (score 1):

At the top bar, use your mouse to scroll over , far right.. your top bar will show XYZ buttons near the end. Depending on the object's origin, select X while you're on edit mode. You should get desired results.

Comment: I'm able to mirror move transformations but have not been able to mirror rotations like I was trying to do in my image above. Could you explain in more detail how to do this?